# Is a translation a orthogonal transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove a translation preserves inner products.

I know intuitively that a translation preserves inner products since they should preserve distances. However I couldn't prove it formally:

If $A:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ defined by $A(w)=w+v$ is a translation by a vector $v$. I couldn't prove that $\langle A(w_1),A(w_2)\rangle=\langle w_1,w_2\rangle$.

Comment: A translation indeed preserves the distance (= the norm of the difference of two vectors), but not the norm of a vector itself.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yeah, I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's wrong: $\langle A(0), A(0)\rangle = \langle v, v\rangle = \| v\|^2 \neq 0 = \langle 0, 0\rangle$. You can find many other counterexamples.

Observe that it's still an isometry (but not a linear one!) with respect to the norm:
$ \| A(w_1) - A(w_2)\| = \| w_1 + v - (w_2 + v)\| = \| w_1 - w_2\|$

Comment: Thank you. That's weird! Translation is supposed to be an isometry.

Comment: @user42912 It's an isometry in the sense of metric spaces, but not in the sense of inner-product spaces.

Comment: The problem is that it's not linear.

Comment: Thank you again. I think I got it.